# Where do I see the registered users in magento 2 admin panel?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, admin-panel

I cannot see the users registered on my Magento 2 website in the customers tab of the admin panel. There is just one entry of the sample data. I am creating accounts but cannot find them in the admin panel.

Comment: thanks
it's working fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please navigate to  Menu `Customers` >`All Customers`.

If the customer does not show at Customer grid then  ***you need a reindex*** for customer grid as magento 2 use flat table for admin customer grid.

**run the command:**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset customer_grid
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit! I also had to use `php bin/magento indexer:reindex customer_grid` along with the command you had provided for it to work.